# how to add the constraints to a UImageView in objective-c

Tags: ios

I am developing an app.while adding the constraints i found error in that.
I am doing in iPad 12.9 and also in iPad 9.7 .So,i set  the images in 12.9 screen screen .That means in Assests folder i stored the two images in that.

1.For background image with of 1366*1024-1x,2732*2048-2x
2.a image with of 160*491-1x,321*985-2x

So how to add the constraints on the background image and a image.
i need to view at correct position.

[i have done on  12.9 screen size.how to add constraints in xcode for this .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj7Cv.jpg) please reply....

Comment: Like background image add constraints on other Imgview, thats all. What is the issue in this.

Comment: i  have edited my question .please check

Comment: @dahiya_boy have edited the question.please check.

Comment: Send me your dummy project, if u can.

Answer (score 0):

you can add constraints to the imageView as follows:

```
   let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

 /* Leading space to superview */
    NSLayoutConstraint *leadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imgView  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:30];

    /* Top space to superview Y*/
    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:258];

    /* Trailing space to superview */
    NSLayoutConstraint *trailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imgView  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:30];

    /* Bottom space to superview Y*/
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.imgView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:258];

    /* 4. Add the constraints to button's superview*/

    [self addConstraints:@[leadingConstraint, topConstraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
```